# Did anything happen with plans for pluggable XPath in dom4j?

Tags: xpath, dom4j

I see discussion on SourceForge in 2010 of plans for dom4j 2.0 that include a pluggable XPath implementation, allowing Jaxen to be replaced. Now it's 2012. Did anything ever come of it? Or, for that matter, is dom4j actively developed?

Answer (score 2):

The final version of dom4j 2.0 is still not with us. The last pre-release version, [dom4j 2.0 Alpha 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2/), came out on April 5th, 2010. The last stable release, [dom4j 1.6.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j/1.6.1/), was made available on May 20th, 2005. The [dom4j news page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=16035) reported this the next day. No news has been posted since then. The site promises an upcoming 1.6.2 “maitance *(sic)* release” but I wouldn’t hold your breath.

According to the [dom4j-commits](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=dom4j-commits) mailing list, the last check-in was on May 12th, 2004 (presumably, subsequent code changes did not make it into the SourceForge repository). The [dom4j-dev](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=dom4j-dev) mailing list has just two messages in the archives for the whole of 2012, both automated emails generated by activity in the bug tracker. The [dom4j-user](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=dom4j-user) mailing list saw its last post in December 2011.

The [dom4j.org](http://www.dom4j.org/) website appears to have fallen into the hands of cyber-squatters some time in 2009.

Looks pretty dead from here.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I'd vote it up if I had 4 more points. :) Too bad. dom4j 1.6.1 can't be used in Eclipse projects.